# How do i make a text output on processing on specific coordinates?

Tags: string, text, processing

I am making a dice generator, which rolls 2 dices a thousand times and gives the output to an array, which is then displayed as bar charts on the graphic output. Now i want to add the dice numbers at the bottom of the chart (and also turn the chart around ), but it doesnt seem like i get any output [this line-> text(String.format("%s",i),i+w*(width/11),280,(width/11),280); ]. Did i place it in the wrong function, because the code should work like that( i ve adapted it from a previous project). [my dice has the numbers 0-5 on it just so i dont get that confused by the array starting at 0, im still fairly new to that]. Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Random;
Random rg = new Random();
final int N=1000;

void setup(){
println(f);
println(p);
size(700,500);
background(255);
}


int [] f=countDice2(N);
float[] p= getProbabilities(f);



int [] countDice2(int N){      
  int[] f = new int [11];
  for(int i =0; i<N;i++){
    int k =rg.nextInt(6);           
    int u= rg.nextInt(6);
    int t =u+k;
    f[t] +=1;
  }
  return f;
}


float[] getProbabilities(int[] f){
  int n=0;
  for(int j=0; j< f.length; j++){
    n=n+f[j];
  }
  float[] prob=new float[f.length];
  for(int i=0; i<f.length;i++){
    prob[i]= (float)f[i]/n;
  }
  return prob;
}

void plotProbabilities(){

  for( int i =0, w =0;w<=11 && i< 11; i++, w++){
    //fill(0,255,0);
    rect(i+w*(width/11) ,300,(width/11),f[0+i]); 


  }

}


void draw(){
    plotProbabilities();
  for( int i =0, w =0;w<=11 && i< 11; i++, w++){
      text(String.format("%s",i),i+w*(width/11),280,(width/11),280);    
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is very simple: you're writing in white.

Look how I found out:

```
void draw() {
  plotProbabilities();
  for ( int i =0, w =0; w<=11 && i< 11; i++, w++) {
    fill(0);
    text("" + i, i+w*(width/11), 280, (width/11), 280);
  }
}
```

Think of `fill()` as changing pencil: everything you do after will use the new pencil, so the new color. If you draw several different things with their own color, you have to specify the `fill` color for every one.

You nailed it. This is just a small mistake.

Have fun!